# twitter bootstrap remove gutter from span in fluid configuration

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have followed this post with no success:

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3445#issuecomment-5640392

i'm using fluid container and row, and i want to remove the gutters between spans.

what exactly do i have to do in order to get spans with no margin-left gutter?
i have used the custom build with property @fluidGridGutterWidth set to 0.
i have even manually added to both responsive and regular css files:
@fluidGridGutterWidth: margin-left:0;!important;
@gridGutterWidth: margin-left:0;!important;

still get this gutters!!!!

please advise
Thanks

Comment: Did you have any luck? I have the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585121/how-to-reduce-gutter-size-to-zero-using-twitter-bootstrap-in-yii ... but no luck fixing it?

Comment: this issue was fixed in custom build for twitter bootstrap 2.2.0 customize option, but i don't see this now, very strange, i guess you need to compile the less files manualy

Answer (score 1):

**Update** Since 2.1 the responsive grid gutters are editable in the `variables.less` file ([see on github](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.1.0/less/variables.less#L257))

```
@gridGutterWidth: 20px;
...
@gridGutterWidth1200: 30px;
...
@gridGutterWidth768: 20px;
```

---

First, the `!important` must be before the `;` like `margin-left: 0!important;`

Secondly, variables should be set with values, not entire rules :

```
@fluidGridGutterWidth: 0;
```

The same goes in functions (example from `responsive-1200px-min.less` file)

```
#grid > .fluid(8.547008547%, 0);
```

Several responsive files are concerned by this *hardcoded* parameter modification. **(version < 2.1 - see update)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. should i set @fluidGridGutterWidth: 0; both on bootstrap.css and the responsive css file? i have did exactly that but still i have gutters margin-left: in % values

Comment: You don't have to set the `@fluidGridGutterWidth` in the responsive files, you have to change the values passed as parameters to `#grid > .XXX(...)` like my example. The second parameter is the gutter width (for static, fluid and input grids). If you don't understand the responsive files, you shouldn't use nor customize the responsive design.

Comment: once again thanks for the answer, where do i change the responsive-1200px-min.less for example? can i build a custom file from the bootstrap site, or do i need to compile css files for this to happen?. thanks

Comment: @saniko You can't change it from the bootstrap site. You'll have to download the less files, modify them, and compile them by your [own means](http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage). Be sure to modify all `responsive-XXXpx...` files.

Comment: Thanks!, on bootstrap site you can build your own custom build: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html, it gives you option to change the gutter apparently it does not work, i will try and look into less

Comment: Seems like it would be appropriate to have a class that we can use to remove the gutter as needed just like with the 960 grid system. I only want to remove the gutter on occasion not for my entire site.

Comment: @JBeckton The grid doesn't support that, but you can easily override the margin with your own class : `.myClass > [class*="span"] { ...!important }`

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, and I swear someone here can answer it in 1 second --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585121/how-to-reduce-gutter-size-to-zero-using-twitter-bootstrap-in-yii ... please help?