# How to reduce gutter size to zero using Twitter Bootstrap in YII?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am using this extension: [Yii-Bootstrap](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap/), along with this less extension: [less](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/less)

In my main.php config file I have:

```
'components'=>array(
  'less'=>array(
    'class'=>'ext.less.components.LessCompiler',
    'forceCompile'=>true, // indicates whether to force compiling
    //'compress'=>false, // indicates whether to compress compiled CSS
    //'debug'=>false, // indicates whether to enable compiler debugging mode
    'paths'=>array(
      'less/style.less'=>'css/style.css',
    ),
  ),
  'bootstrap'=>array(
      'class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
      'responsiveCss'=>true,
  ),
```

The bootstrappy goodness works. My problem is that I'm trying to modify the variables in protected\extensions\bootstrap\lib\bootstrap\less\variables.less:

```
@gridGutterWidth:         0px;
@gridGutterWidth1200:     0px;
@gridGutterWidth768:      0px;
```

However, these changes don't reflect anywhere on the site, even though I'm editing variables.less directly. This leads me to believe that it's not variables.less that I must edit.

Any idea how I can change the gutters?

UPDATE: I was able to edit the following file and see changes:

```
protected\extensions\bootstrap\assets\css\bootstrap-responsive.css
```

I changed:

```
[class*="span"] {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

To:

```
[class*="span"] {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

This now takes away the gutters. But doesn't quite solve my problem. I wanted this to all happen dynamically via YII and LESS. How do I do that?

Comment: How do  you use this less file? Include this file on main layout with less.js? Or complile it into .css...
Please post the code

Comment: I use this: 'responsiveCss'=>true,

Comment: where? You use Yii-Bootstrap extension?

Comment: Yes, I use bootstrap extension. I will quickly update the question.

Comment: Updated with as muich info as I could add. Anything else needed to answer this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set responsiveCss to false:

```
'bootstrap'=>array(
  'class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
  'responsiveCss'=> false,
),
```

And then to change my style.less file to include:

```
// Import the Bootstrap mixins, operations and functions so that you can use them in this file.
@import "../protected/extensions/bootstrap/lib/bootstrap/less/mixins.less";
@import "../protected/extensions/bootstrap/lib/bootstrap/less/variables.less";
@import "../protected/extensions/bootstrap/lib/bootstrap/less/scaffolding.less";
@import "../protected/extensions/bootstrap/lib/bootstrap/less/responsive.less";
```

The confusion came in with "responsiveCss", which wasn't clearly explained (anywhere). Basically this will copy the css files from protected\extensions\bootstrap\assets\css\ and include it into your file, with no modifications. What I mention above, is how you would move from the "standard" version, to this "customizable" way.

Hope that helps someone, because it wasted a lot of my time, not to mention the time I have to spend redoing css now.