# Customizing Bootstrap Gutter Width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to remove the gutter spacing in the grid layout of twitterbootstrap.  I don't want there to be any gutter at all.

I went to the customize page for Twitter Bootstrap:

```
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html
```

I set

```
@gridGutterWidth
@gridGutterWidth1200
@gridGutterWidth768
```

to 0px

When I download it and unzip the file I get error.txt files inside that say the following:

> A less error occured trying to build your bundle. You've likely entered an invalid input into the less variable field. Check your syntax and try again!
>
> thanks!

I tried it again setting them to just 1px and I got the same errors.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot duplicate the error. I'm on a Win 7 machine accessing the site by Firefox 19. When I set them to 0px, I get no error files on download.

Comment: Interesting.  I had been using Chrome.  I opened the site in IE and was able to download it successfully.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to be a less syntax issue that is demonstrated properly on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824074/twitter-bootstrap-remove-gutter-from-span-in-fluid-configuration)

Edit the less file to:

```
@gridGutterWidth: 0px;
@gridGutterWidth1200: 0px;
@gridGutterWidth1200: 0px;
```

Then recompile it to see if it works. Happy Styling!

Answer (score 0):

I was using Chrome when I got the errors.  I opened the site in IE and entered 0px for the 3 properties I mentioned and it worked successfully.